# In HTML/ColdFusion, how do I jump to a position in a list?

Tags: html, coldfusion, anchor

I have a long customer list created using a CFQUERY. I want to display the letters A through Z above the list as anchors and when one is selected, go to that position on the customer list. I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is accomplished using HTML anchor tags. Has nothing to do with ColdFusion. What have you tried so far?  [ask]

Comment: I know I'll need anchor tags, but I'm not sure how to direct the anchors (26 of them) to point to a changing spot in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the Last Name's first letter as **a separate column** of your query, using SQL ***LEFT()***:

```
<cfquery name="getCustomers">
  SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, LEFT(C.LastName,1) AS FirstLetter
  FROM Customers C
  ORDER BY C.LastName
</cfquery>
```

then, when you output the names in HTML, you can use the **group** attribute of `<cfoutput>` to handle each letter.

First make the index:

```
<cfoutput query="getCustomers" group="FirstLetter">
  <a href="##Letter#FirstLetter#">#FirstLetter#</a> |
</cfoutput>
```

This will make a list like

> [A](http://www.a.comn) | [B](http://www.a.comn) | [C](http://letter.com) | [F](http://letter.com) | [G](http://letter.com) | [K](http://letter.com) |

where each letter is linked to the HTML anchor and missing letters are skipped, obviously, since they were not selected by the query. (I can't make them show the right link to anchors on this post, not sure how)

Then output the names list with an anchor at the beginning of each group:

```
<cfoutput query="getCustomers" group="FirstLetter">
  <a name="Letter#FirstLetter#"><hr /></a>
  <cfoutput><p>#FirstName# #LastName#</p></cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

So it will look like

> ---
>
> John Adams
> Mary Aaronson
>
> ---
>
> Jack Barber
>
> ---
>
> Kate Collins

etc, where each hard ruler is the list anchor

You know how the group attribute works, yes? If not, just [look it up](http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/01/displaying-a-grouped-query-using-nested-cfoutput-tags-in-coldfusion/).

(*) the above is "pseudo-CF", it lacks datasource attributes on the query etc. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score -1):

heres a try;

```
<cfquery name="RetrieveNames" datasource="#DataSource#">
    SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM tblContacts
            ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
</cfquery>

<cfset LastFirstLetter="">

<cfoutput query="RetrieveNames">
<cfif Left(LastName,1) is not LastFirstLetter>
    <cfset LastFirstLetter = Left(LastName,1)>
    <a href="###LastFirstLetter#">#LastFirstLetter#</a>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>

<hr>

<cfset LastFirstLetter="">

<cfoutput query="RetrieveNames">
<cfif Left(LastName,1) is not LastFirstLetter>
    <cfset LastFirstLetter = Left(LastName,1)>
    <a name="#LastFirstLetter#"></a><b>#LastFirstLetter#</b>
    <hr>
</cfif>
#LastName#, #FirstName#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

i did want to do a query of queries like this;

```
<cfquery name="RetrieveLetters" dbtype="query">
    select substr(LastName,1,1) as FirstLetter
            from RetrieveNames
            group by substr(LastName,1,1)
</cfquery>
```

but i couldn't get that to work. but if you could, then you could just loop through that when you build the href links, you wouldn't have the unnecessary looping that it currently has ... maybe someone can improve it

Comment: Thanks! What happens if the user selects "D" and there is no name starting with "D"?  And for the first pair, how do I specify which field to search? (The client wants to be able to sort two different fields.

Comment: only output the hrefs for letters you know will be there, you'll have that info in the query anyway - you could loop through it initially building the href links. for the second part, i'm not sure what you mean - this isn't searching anything - just jumping to a position in the page

Comment: Never mind. I see what you're saying here. I need all the code you gave - the first pair where the anchor tags are and the second pair positioned within the list. Sorry for the dumb comments.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin i've updated my answer, but it could do with improving as i mention